# Decodificar dados em Base64

Tags: python, string, base64

Estou trabalhando com metadados de uma imagem extraídos em formato Json. Um desses dados é uma string binária **base64**. Li em uma documentação que esses valores são de **16 bits**. Há alguma forma de decodifica-los e manda-los para uma matriz automaticamente? As soluções que tentei são todas para valores 8 bits.

Answer (score 2):

Para 'decodificar' um dado representado em [`base64`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) você pode usar a função [`b64decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64decode) do módulo [`base64`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) da seguinte forma:

```
import base64
b64 = 'TyByYXRvIHJvZXUgYSByb3VwYSBkbyByZWkgZGUgUm9tYQ=='
print base64.b64decode(b64)
```

Saída:

```
O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma
```

Answer (score 2):

Sobre o Base64 não tem nada a ver com "16 bits". Como o nome indica, a sua mensagem é quebrada em pedaços representáveis por 64 caracteres, ou seja: *6 bits*. Usando-se esse subconjunto da tabela total de 256 caracteres (8 bits), se garante que os dados são todos representados por caracteres visíveis e imprimíveis. Isso garante que qualquer conteúdo pode ser, por exemplo, copiado e colado em aplicações de usuário: pares de chave criptográfica usam esse recurso de representação, por exemplo.

Também garante que qualquer conteúdo sempre vá ser transmitido na integra, mesmo por protocolos de Internet que só transmitem texto puro.. Esse era o caso das primeiras versões dos padrões de e-mail, por exemplo. Até hoje, quando se anexa uma imagem num e-mail, internamente ela vai anexada como base64 ou alguma variante (base85, por exemplo). Na sua caixa de entrada de e-mails pode haver uma opção de "ver mensagem original", ou "raw" - selecione isso e veja como imagens, do tipo assinaturas vem codificadas como base64.

Em Python, para decodificar um trecho de dados em base64 e similares há um módulo pronto na biblioteca padrão que já faz tudo, chamado "base64". Basta chamar a função `base64.b64decode` passando o seu texto codificado, e vai ter o conteúdo original na forma de um objeto  "bytes". Basta salvar esse objeto como um arquivo binário no disco para se ter o arquivo de imagem:

```
dados = {"imagem": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAcAAAAHCAAAAADhOQgPAAAAI0lEQVQI1yXGsQ0AMBDEIO7339kp0iDWiJMMSa6Fr3WYtn4ev0gPAtGQ50YAAAAASUVORK5CYII="}
import base64
imagem = base64.b64decode(dados["imagem"])
with open("image.png", "wb") as img_file:
    img_file.write(imagem)
```

Para ter 64 símbolos, o formato usa as letras de A a Z maiúsculas e minúsculas (52 caractéres), mais os dígitos de 0 a 9 (64) e os símbolos + e /, totalizando 64 dígitos. O sinal de "=" ainda é usado para marcar números "0" que não entram nos dados decodificados, quando o número de bytes originais não for divisivel por 3. Assim, cada 3 bytes de 8 bits da mensagem original são convertidos para 4 dígitos de 6 bits. Quebras de linha são ignoradas, permitindo que os dados possam ser formatados de forma que possam ser impressos de um jeito "bonitinho".